# Test if a mapped drive exists

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Right now this creates a text file and puts it in dfs\Data_Public\Public\TSC\VirusCommands which is a mapped drive.

**Now what I need help with is sometimes we scan other peoples computers that aren't allowed to have that mapped drive. I've been stuck trying to find a new way. I was thinking a IF ELSE statement to put it into my Downloads or some where temporary or just have it open up notepad so we could copy the file but each time I've tried it just doesn't work.**
If any of you guys have ideas I'd love to hear them!

```
set tscdest="dfs\Data_Public\Public\TSC\VirusCommands"

::Create the destination folder if it does not already exist
mkdir "%tscdest%"

::Delete any existing file for this computer
type NUL > "%tscdest%\%USERNAME%.txt"

::Send the output from the commands into the text file
hostname >> "%tscdest%\%USERNAME%.txt"





echo. >> "%tscdest%\%USERNAME%.txt"
echo ------------- >> "%tscdest%\%USERNAME%.txt"
echo ipconfig /all >> "%tscdest%\%USERNAME%.txt"
echo ------------- >> "%tscdest%\%USERNAME%.txt"
ipconfig /all >> "%tscdest%\%USERNAME%.txt"

echo. >> "%tscdest%\%USERNAME%.txt"
echo ---------- >> "%tscdest%\%USERNAME%.txt"
echo query user >> "%tscdest%\%USERNAME%.txt"
echo ---------- >> "%tscdest%\%USERNAME%.txt"
echo. >> "%tscdest%\%USERNAME%.txt"
query user >> "%tscdest%\%USERNAME%.txt"

echo. >> "%tscdest%\%USERNAME%.txt"
echo ------------ >> "%tscdest%\%USERNAME%.txt"
echo netstat -ano >> "%tscdest%\%USERNAME%.txt"
echo ------------ >> "%tscdest%\%USERNAME%.txt"
netstat -ano >> "%tscdest%\%USERNAME%.txt"

echo. >> "%tscdest%\%USERNAME%.txt"
echo -------- >> "%tscdest%\%USERNAME%.txt"
echo tasklist >> "%tscdest%\%USERNAME%.txt"
echo -------- >> "%tscdest%\%USERNAME%.txt"
tasklist >> "%tscdest%\%USERNAME%.txt"`
```

Comment: Have you tried using an EXISTS in an if statement?

Comment: I've tried to use an EXIST I  just don't think i'm doing it right either?

Comment: `IF EXIST "%tscdest%\%USERNAME%.txt" (
        del "%tscdest%\%USERNAME%.txt"
    ) ELSE (
        echo "%download%\%USERNAME%.txt"
    )`
Here is what i've tried...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use EXIST, which works like this:

```
IF EXIST "%tscdest%" set tscdest="%USERPROFILE%/Downloads"
```

And put that at the top of your batch file

Comment: I guess i'm confused by that a little. So its saying IF dfs\Data_Public\Public\TSC\VirusCommands EXIST then write there? Or else write to "%USERPROFILE%/Downloads?

Comment: Yes. %USERPROFILE% should be the path to your users home directory btw.